# C# how to change Language version in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I can not change the language version in VS 2019, the field is disabled, why? how to enable it?

[image]

Comment: Starting from .net core 3.x it's relying on installed sdk

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LangVersion` tag in your Project file, [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference)

> The latest C# compiler determines a default language version based on
> your project's target framework or frameworks. Visual Studio doesn't
> provide a UI to change the value, **but you can change it by editing the
> csproj file.**

E.g

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
  <LangVersion>Latest</LangVersion>
   ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Or any found here [C# language version reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#c-language-version-reference)

However read the notes, only some version are available in certain frameworks. And some are only partially supported